# How to visualize gene networks and cluster groups of genes?

Tags: cluster-analysis, bioinformatics

I'm working with biological data - namely groups of genes. For example:

```
group 1: geneA geneB geneC
group 2: geneD geneE
group 3: geneF geneG geneH
```

For each pair of genes, `geneX` and `geneY` I have a score telling how similiar the two genes are (actually, I have two scores, since I used BLAST which is 'directional': I first searched `geneX` against all the other genes then `geneY` against all the other genes, so I have two `geneX--geneY` scores, but I guess I can take the lower score of the two, or the average).

So, let's suppose I have only one score for each pair of genes. My data can be viewed as a undirected graph:
[image]

and recall each edge has a score attached to it.

Now, what I would like to do is:

1. Visualize my data interactively: being able to click on gene nodes
   and open a link attached to them, show only edges above/below some threshold, control how the network is "spread", etc.
2. Cluster together **groups** which
       are similar, i.e. groups that have
       similar genes.

Any ideas of how can I do that? I guess it's basic clustering and I would appreciate any hints on packages/software that can be of any help here.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably get better responses if you ask this over at [BioStar](http://biostar.stackexchange.com/), the bioinformatics stackexchange. 
Specifically, many of the answers in this thread might be relevant:

[Which is the best software to represent biological pathways in a directed graph (network) ?](http://biostar.stackexchange.com/questions/2451/which-is-the-best-software-to-represent-biological-pathways-in-a-directed-graph)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [cluto](http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/views/cluto/). You will have to transform your triples (gene_1, gene_2, similarity) into a matrix and use 'scluster'.